# Options for Replacing 60w Magsafe Power Supply

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, power, magsafe

For the second time in four weeks I've had to re-solder the mag safe cord back on to the power supply. This time, unlike the first, the cord broke on the negative terminal on the circuit board itself. I was able to put a dab of solder back on the terminal to keep the power supply working, but the connection is weak, and I'm not sure how long it's going to last (I repack my charger a few times a day when I'm in school).

To that end, my question is this: would it be possible to solder the proprietary end of the (i.e. the magsafe cord) of the a/c adapter to a generic 60w adapter? I'm no electrician, but it seems as though nearly all 60w power supplies would be more or less equal in the whole scheme of things, but I could be wrong, and I don't want to fry my laptop.

Has anyone tried this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 60 Watt is not 60 Watt. Does it has the Voltage? the Current and the identification (the middle pin)

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot just arbitrarily solder the cord from the MagSafe Power Supply on to a generic 60w power supply as the output voltage and amperage need to be matched as well.

That said, since you're having issues where it's connecting to the power supply I have to assume your starting off by wrapping the cord to tight around its ears.  You're not supposed to bend it tight at it base!  Start wrapping it by allowing it to stay sticking straight out from the power supply, as in the picture below, and then start a bend to wrap it around the ears.

My previous MacBook Pro which I had for 7 years I wrapped it as in the picture and never had and issue with it.  I still have the old MBP and power supply and it looks a good as the two year old one in the picture below.

[image: MagSafe Power Supplu]

Comment: Glad to hear that your magsafe cable hasn't had any issues in the 7 years you've owned it, though I think it's worth mentioning that Apple did have a power adapter replacement program for this very issue because of the faulty design.

Unfortunately I was late to the table.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/TS4127